# A version of Weak Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $L=K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a finitely generated ring. If $L$ is  field, then each $x_i$ is algebraic over $K$.

(Proof of this can be done if we verify it for $n=1$ - am I right? If $L=K[x_1]$ is a field, then $1/x_1$ will be a polynomial in $x_1$, which gives us that it is algebraic over $K$.)

**Q.** In the book Linear Algebraic Groups by Humphreys, author calls this theorem as Weak Nullstellensatz; in what sense it is weak Nullstellensatz compared to Hilbert's Nullstellensatz?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page, this result is usually called Zarisk’s Lemma, and can be used to prove Hilbert’s NSS, which states that the ideal $I(V(J)$ of polynomials vanishing on $V(J)$, the common zero locus (over an algebraic closure) of elements from $J$, is precisely the radical $\sqrt J$.

Comment: The weak NSS is usually the statement that if $J$ is a proper ideal, then the common zero locus $V(J)$ (over an algebraic closure) is non-empty.